# Battleship AI without being notified of a ship being sunk

Tags: artificial-intelligence

So basically, I have to write a Battleships AI, which follows all of the conventional rules, apart from the fact that you are not notified whether or not your shot has sunk a ship - just whether or not it was a hit or miss
At the moment I have a working AI, but it suffers from the problem that it has to fire shots all the way around each enemy ship, as it doesn't know if the ship is sunk - this video may explain it better (for those who are wondering, there are some custom ship shapes, and the board is an L-shape): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzLspp4JzNE
Any suggestions on how to go about reducing the number of shots required?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What information the computer can have? Number of ships, number of blocks for each ship, the shape of each ship. The algorithm has to check for the shapes of all remaining ships and pick next field such that the chance of hit is largest. Maybe there is a better long term strategy than "greatest hit chance", but solve the shape recognition part before delving into strategies.

If shapes of the ships are not known in advance then there's not much the algorithm can do. All it can is to check if the block being hit is the part of the largest remaining ship. The advanced strategy here would be to determine if largest ship cannot be anywhere else. If there are other ships remaining then use turns to search for them, but in such a search pattern that you also eliminate the possibility of the largest ship being somewhere else.

However, if there is a rule of number of attacks per turn being in proportion with number of your remaining ships, then you have to eliminate every ship as soon as possible, and so the "advanced" strategy above should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic idea is to keep information regarding sunked ships as well as remaining ones (I assume that you know, that there are `a_i` ships with `i` pieces), and ones you sunk all the 4-pieces, and hit some connected 3-piece ship you will know, that there is no need to shoot around it anymore. So in general you shoot around hitted ship as long, as amount of hitted pieces is smaller that the number of pieces in the biggest non-empty class of ships. And once you sunk some - you decrease the respective ship class counter.

Some interesting alternative would be to learn some statistics of ships positions and shapes based on played games - if you play against human player it is most probable, that he won't place any ship anywhere - there are some psychological aspects that "bias" your decisions towards placements that you consider as "hard to find" - your program could learn such conditional probabilities and use it to assume its confidency in sunking some ship without shooting around it. Unfortunately this would not work with well designed - uniformly placing ships - algorithms.